# While creating SPFx webpart solution, i am getting the error : EINTEGRITY?

Tags: office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts

All these packages like Node, NPM, Yomen, Gulp, microsoft/Sharepoint-generator are already installed as mentioned in the help document for creating a new SPFx solution.
https://www.sharepointsky.com/sharepoint-framework-development/

When i am trying to create a new project using yo @microsoft/sharepoint, after providing all the input values, I am getting the below error.

Error:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-Pxm6sI2MeBD7RdD12RYsqaP0nMiwx8eZBXCa6z2L+mRHm2DYrOYwihmhjpkdjUHwQhslWQjRpEgNq4XvBmaAuw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-Pxm6sI2MeBD7RdD12RYsqaP0nMiwx8eZBXCa6z2L+mRHm2D
YrOYwihmhjpkdjUHwQhslWQjRpEgNq4XvBmaAuw== but got sha512-b8TD4/34N7Aj6IXPmmA5IyBcW7dnVvURvGxWwVxA54dfC1Hb+faFVsBYOJR+3yCTxpkdRg3Ajt/TQkNppV6viw==. (1593 bytes)
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1) Delete package-lock.json

2) Delete node_modules

3) `npm cache clear -f`

4) `npm install`

5) `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`

Comment: I am setting up this environment in my corporate machine.
What access and permission are essential in running following the command to install yomen  and gulp ...

npm install -g gulp 
or
npm install -g yo

Do i need to open CMD with administrator rights ? Do my network would need any special proxy settings to install these packages ? Please share your thoughts on this ... Thanks in advance !